# My Arduino got stuck and continuous looping in if condition

Tags: arduino-uno, rtc

I'm using RTC and when the if condition is true the Time gots stuck and the condition keeps looping. Please help

Here is my code:

```
// CONNECTIONS:
// DS1302 CLK/SCLK --> 5
// DS1302 DAT/IO --> 4
// DS1302 RST/CE --> 2
// DS1302 VCC --> 3.3v - 5v
// DS1302 GND --> GND
#include <Servo.h> 
#include <ThreeWire.h>  
#include <RtcDS1302.h>

ThreeWire myWire(4,5,2); // IO, SCLK, CE
RtcDS1302<ThreeWire> Rtc(myWire);
int servoPin = 3;
Servo Servo1;
void setup () 
{
    Serial.begin(57600);
    Servo1.attach(servoPin);
//    Serial.print("compiled: ");
//    Serial.print(__DATE__);
    Serial.println(__TIME__);

    Rtc.Begin();

    RtcDateTime compiled = RtcDateTime(__TIME__);
    printDateTime(compiled);
    Serial.println();

    if (Rtc.GetIsWriteProtected())
    {
        Serial.println("RTC was write protected, enabling writing now");
        Rtc.SetIsWriteProtected(false);
    }

    if (!Rtc.GetIsRunning())
    {
        Serial.println("RTC was not actively running, starting now");
        Rtc.SetIsRunning(true);
    }

    RtcDateTime now = Rtc.GetDateTime();
    if (now < compiled) 
    {
        Serial.println("RTC is older than compile time!  (Updating DateTime)");
        Rtc.SetDateTime(compiled);
    }
    else if (now > compiled) 
    {
        Serial.println("RTC is newer than compile time. (this is expected)");
    }
    else if (now == compiled) 
    {
        Serial.println("RTC is the same as compile time! (not expected but all is fine)");
    }
}

void loop () 
{
    RtcDateTime now = Rtc.GetDateTime();

    printDateTime(now);
    Serial.println();
    delay(5000);

//here is my problem>>>>


    if(now.Hour() == 22 && now.Minute() == 40)
    {
      Servo1.write(0);
      delay(1000);
      Servo1.write(90);
      delay(1000);

    }  

//////////////////////

    delay(5000); 


}

#define countof(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))

void printDateTime(const RtcDateTime& dt)
{
    char datestring[20];
//%02u/%02u/%04u
    snprintf_P(datestring, 
            countof(datestring),
            PSTR("%02u:%02u:%02u"),
//            dt.Month(),
//            dt.Day(),
//            dt.Year(),
            dt.Hour(),
            dt.Minute(),
            dt.Second() );
    Serial.print(datestring);
}
```

Comment: Um... What does "Time gots stuck" mean? Your condition is true for a whole minute.

Comment: when the condition is true the time interval of rtc gots stuck and the codition above keeps looping

Comment: It is `loop()` function keeps looping. That's what it is for, as the name suggests. What made you believe that "time interval of rtc gots stuck" is not clear to me.

Comment: The time is stuck and the condition keeps triggering..

Comment: What made you believe that "the time is stuck"??? The condition **should** keep triggering again, again and again for a whole minute. That's what you wrote in your code.

Comment: Im looking in serial monitor and the time got stuck when the condition is reach. And it keeps triggering the servo again and again..

Comment: Post the serial monitor output from `printDateTime(now);` in `loop()`. Do you see the same time printed continuously?

Comment: The ds1302 is not a good rtc, the ds1307 is better, but the ds3231 is the best by far. The ds1302 can freeze and there can be troubles with the crystal. Could you upgrade to a ds3231. The ds3231 has an internal crystal, so there are no problems with bad quality crystals.

Comment: AnT It stuck on condition and the servo keeps triggered 5 to 10 times and the time continue after triggering.

Comment: Im not using crystal

Comment: i think i have a problem in delay seconds

Comment: `Im not using crystal` -- So.... how does the clock "tick" then...?

Comment: You do know that a minute lasts for a whole minute, don't you? It's not some instantaneous thing that only happens for an instant. It's a minute long. A lot can happen in a minute.

Comment: The delays in your `loop()` amount for 12 seconds. So it is perfectly expected to see this if triggered ~5 times per minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is being brought to your attention is the following part of your code...

```
//here is my problem>>>>

if(now.Hour() == 22 && now.Minute() == 40)
{
  Servo1.write(0);
  delay(1000);
  Servo1.write(90);
  delay(1000);
}
```

In this code you use an "if" statement and ask:
   if the now.Hour is equal 22 AND if the now.Minute is equal 40 then
    write a 0 to your servo then
    delay for 1000
    then write a 90 to your servo
    and wait another 1000

What is being brought to your attention is that until now.Hour changes or
until now.Minute changes your write 0, delay, write 90, delay will continue
on and on and on until now.Hour changes (which will take a while) or now.Minute
changes. Since minutes are 60 seconds long your code will repeat for all of those
60 seconds...

If you were to change your code to include, oh, lets say now.Second() (like this)--

```
if(now.Hour() == 22 && now.Minute() == 40 && now.Second() == 00)
```

Then your code will repeat over and over until now.Second changes (which will take 1 second).

By the time your loop gets back to the "if" statement now.Second will no longer be 00 and it will not be "stuck" for you...

---

As has been brought to my attention, your 5 second delay will be a problem, so you might find that changing it will allow the now.Second "fix" to work.

In the following part of your code change delay(5000)

```
void loop () 
{
    RtcDateTime now = Rtc.GetDateTime();

    printDateTime(now);
    Serial.println();
    delay(5000);
}
```

to something like delay(1000) or so.

That way it will only wait 1 second before dropping out of the loop and checking the loop with the newly added now.Second(). This will make the printDateTime(now) happen every second instead of every 5 seconds, but it shouldn't get "stuck".

Hopefully this helps you to better understand how time (and its parts) work.

Comment: a state variable would be a much better solution. with the 5 sec delay in loop() the code could miss the exact second

Comment: Aiming for the exact equality with the scheduled time is a bad approach, regardless of how short the delay is. The proper condition should look as `(current_time >= scheduled_time && event_has_not_been_triggered_yet)`. I.e. it should be a greater-or-equal comparison, not an equality comparison.

Comment: Ah, experience speaks! I like that, a much better solution...

Comment: This approach might be further modified with extra tweaks like: if the above condition is true, but *too much* time has passed since the scheduled time (due to some unfortunate blocking operation in `loop()`), then just abandon the event. Depends on the specific application. Sounding an alarm to wake people 
up on a weekday morning is typically not a "discardable" event. Feeding the cat, if it is already well past its bedtime, probably is.

Comment: Thank you Alexander!  I do not know how to use the 'editor' as well as you, I was unable to add the OP's original code as well as you.  Again, thanks!

Comment: You can use four `space`s to [mark](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) it as a code block.